# Can a Stream be listened to once at a time or once in general?

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

I have this StreamController:

`StreamController<Workout> _selectedWorkoutSubject = new StreamController()`

I listen to it in a StreamBuilder like this:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: workoutBloc.selectedWorkoutStream,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Workout> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ...
    } else {
      return Text('loading...');
    }
  }
);
```

When I leave the current page and return to it, I get the Exception: `Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.` I know I can only once at a time but isn't that what I'm doing? When I leave the page, the StreamBuilder should get Garbage collected which frees the stream, so something else could listen to it.

Or can a Stream only be listend to once in general (Not once at a time)? I know I can just do

```
StreamController<Workout> _selectedWorkoutSubject = new StreamController.broadcast();
```

But I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work the way I originally did it.

Comment: I'd post a bit more of the code including where you are assigning workoutBloc and the stream there.

Comment: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/broadcast-streams

Answer (score 3):

It's not "one at a time". A traditional non-broadcast stream can only be listened to once, ever. It only allows one listener, and when that listener cancels, the stream cleans up after itself and won't work again.

A traditional broadcast stream can be listened to many times, but all concurrent listeners get the same events.

Most `Stream` constructors and `StreamController`s create either traditional "single-subscription" streams or broadcast streams.

There has been added another way to create a stream which can be listened to more than once: The [`Stream.multi`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/Stream.multi.html) constructor.
With that, you can treat each `listen` call individually, and send whichever events you want to them, not necessarily the same values all listeners (each `listen` call gets its own indivudual `StreamController`).

You can implement the behavior of a broadcast stream using that, but you don't have to.

Other than that, using a broadcast stream is your best choice. The broadcast stream controller does get `onCancel` and `onListen` events when it stops having listeners and starts having listeners again, so you can avoid doing work when there are no listeners.
With `Stream.multi`, you have to keep record of all the listeners yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try a few things:

1. Set the initial data of the stream builder
2. Change the StreamController to a BehaviorSubject (RxDart lib)

I think the first tip will help you out,